# Prove every interval of a lattice is a sublattice.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

To prove this I think I will have to prove that every interval of a lattice (which is a subset of that lattice) is closed under both meet and join operation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that your interval is $I=[a,b]=\{x\in L:a\le x\le b\}$, where $L$ is the original lattice. Clearly $\langle I,\le\rangle$ is a poset, so as you say, all that remains is to show that if $x,y\in I$, then $x$ and $y$ have both a meet and a join in $\langle I,\le\rangle$. You know that they have a meet and join in $L$. Show that if $u=x\land y$ and $v=x\lor y$ in $L$, then $u\in I$, $v\in I$, and moreover $u$ is the greatest lower bound and $v$ the least upper bound of $x$ and $y$ in $I$ as well as in $L$. To show that $u,v\in I$ you’ll want to use the fact that $a$ is a lower and $b$ an upper bound for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Taking the lattice L = { 1,2,3,4,6,12} . Relation is divides. Now if we take interval [1,3] = {1,2,3} . We can't find the LUB of {2,3}. Then how is the interval [1,3] a lattice?

Comment: @user221458: $2$ isn’t in the interval $[1,3]$, because $2\nmid 3$: $[1,3]=\{1,3\}$.

Comment: ok. Now let me clear my doubt about intervals first.
[1,6] = {1,2,3,6}
[1,4] = {1,2,4}
[2,12] = {2,4,6,12}
Is it right?

Comment: @user221458: Looks good to me.

Comment: Let me try to define intervals of a lattice. If the relation is divides. [a,b] = set of all elements x where x is the multiple of a and x is also the factor of b. Am i right?

Comment: @user221458: Yes, that’s right. Whatever the order relation $\preceq$ of the lattice actually is, $[a,b]$ is the set of all elements $x$ of the lattice such that $a\preceq x\preceq b$. In your lattice that means that $a\mid x$ and $x\mid b$.

Comment: a is a upper bound and b is a lower bound. Therefore a<= x.y and x+y <= b . Now as u = x.y and v = x+y.  
 a<=u and v<=b . Thus , LUB and GLB of any x,y belonging to I is inside the interval. Thus I is a lattice. Correct?

Comment: @user221458: Looks good.

Comment: @user221458: You’re welcome.